How to identify liquidity pool burns in Sol Incinerator and determine authority in Solana?
When a liquidity pool is burned in Sol Incinerator on Solana, will the associated token always have Raydium as the authority? Additionally, how can I filter transactions to specifically identify when a liquidity pool burn has occurred?
